# How to send "Esc" key as a keyword in Robot Framework

Tags: python-2.7, robotframework

I need to send "Esc" key after a Testcase in Robot Framework.

For Example:

```
Click Team Combat
    clickTeamCombat
    sleep       2

<<<< NEED TO PRESS ESC KEY HERE >>>>

Click Settings
    clickSettings
```

I have written a function in python (Sikuli Env) as shown below and called this as Library in RFW:

```
def clickEsckey(self):
    type(key.ESC)
```

I am getting following error:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Click Esc key                                                         | FAIL |
NameError: global name 'key' is not defined
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Could anyone please suggest any ideas to fix this?

Comment: `Press Key \27` didn't work?

Comment: @Burhan Khalid Could you please tell me, how to use this in Robot Framework as a keyword?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid, you are providing the correct answer; just one thing: you have to escape backslash which means the command should be `Press Key    \\27`

Comment: As Burhan says, you should use the selenium library keyword `Press Key` with argument `\\27`; you don't need any self-defined keyword. I'm gonna let @BurhanKhalid to write an answer for you as he is the first one who came up with the solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SeleniumLibrary with Robot framework, then you use the `Press Keys` keyword for send `ESC` key on the currently active browser.

```
Press Keys    None    ESC
```

or

```
Press Keys    <Your locator>    ESC
```

**Full sample** if you empty a bootstrap date picker and escape:

```
Clear Bootstrap DatePicker
    [Arguments]  ${locator}
    Clear Input Text  ${locator}
    Press Keys    ${locator}    ESC

Clear Bootstrap DatePicker  id:your-datepicker-id
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to import sikuli?

```
from sikuli import *
```